# Text from textareas into database makes <br>

Tags: mysql, textarea, line-breaks

When I insert text from a textarea into the database, it will insert the text with enters. No 
 enters, but hard enters, and every enter is on the end of the textbox line. So for example this will be the text in the database:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
Aenean massa.

```
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et 
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque 
eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis 
enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet 
nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus 
ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam 
dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer 
tincidunt. 

Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper 
nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo 
ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend 
ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra 
quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla 
ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean 
imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. 
Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget 
dui.
```

Instead of

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
```

How is that possible and can I remove the hard breaks from the textarea?

Comment: It doesn't make `<br/>`, it makes `\n` (or some other linebreak character, not a tag)

Comment: Thanks, but the \n is not stored in the database field. So how can I insert the text without the linebreaks?

Comment: Yes it is, and you can get rid of it by replacing out all `\n` characters before you insert into the database.

Comment: I used str_replace("\n", "", $string) but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str_replace("\r\n", "", $string)`

Comment: That works! Only problem is that if the user inputs a enter into the textfield, that it also will be removed.

Comment: @Jordy Isn't that what you asked for

Comment: Is that not what I implied no less than 8 minutes earlier @Asad?

Comment: @hd1 I'm not sure what you're implying you implied. If you're talking about your solution, no my solution is different from yours, which is a (somewhat irrelevant) example of the use of a mysql function.

Comment: Oke, very stupid, but I had this on the textarea: wrap='physical'. Sorry:P

Answer (score 1):

Would [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) be of use here:

```
SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
 -> 'WwWwWw.mysql.com'
```

Comment: I don't think so. The problem is that mysql inserts a linebreak after each end of the line in the textarea:S

Comment: Are you sure it isn't that there is a linebreak after each line in the textarea as seen by MySQL? What is your client language?

Comment: It insert the text into the database with hard enters, I don't see \n or <br>. It's stored into latin1_swedish_ci. HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE returns: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4